# Setting UIView's backgroundColor in loadView has no effect

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios7

I have a `UIDatePicker` in an iOS 7 app.  It's added to a view controller (subclass) and it shows up hardly readable because the background is black.  (A date picker needs a light background.)

```
- (void)loadView
{
    self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
    ...
    [self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];

    // When placed here, without viewDidAppear, background remains black/transparent
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // When places here, the background becomes indeed white.
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

I could of course set the background color of the date picker itself in `loadView`, and that's what I ended up doing.

But still I don't understand why setting the super view's background color in `loadView` did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated documentation the [`loadView`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW1) is called when ever the viewcontrollers view property is accessed and the view property is `nil`. If a NIB is associated with the controller his method wil load the view rom the NIB if not it will create a view.

The documentation also states that if you custom implementation should not call super, but this will require you to create your own view.

```
self.view = [UIView new]
```

There is no `self.view` because you did not to call `[super loadView];`, calling super will create the view for you. But you should create your own view if you are overriding this method. As stated in the documentation.

**Beter** is to use [`viewDidLoad`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW25) this called when the view is loaded, either from NIB, storyboard or programmatically.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{
    self.datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];

    [self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer!

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `-viewDidLoad` instead of `-loadView`.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be setting the background color in `-viewWillAppear:`. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW16) for 
`-[UIViewController loadView]`:

> The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property.

I haven't tested it *today*, but I read this to say `self.view` is `nil` when `-loadView` is called, and until you set it explicitly. The main reason to override `-loadView` is to customize the `UIViewController`'s `view` property, presumably to use a specific subclass of `UIView`, rather than the generic.